# Using post type archive page for taxonomy archive

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I have separate post type archive and taxonomy archive page. eg. `archive-product.php` and `taxonomy-price.php`.

So when i goto `example.com/product/?price=100` it redirect to `example.com/price/100` and using the `taxonomy-price.php` to display the posts.
It seem the wp take the priority of taxonomy to display to posts.

So what I want is using the `archive-product.php` to display the posts,how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [Wordpress Template Hierarchy Diagram](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) To get an idea how wordpress choose the tempalte. I'm not sure but according to the Wordpress Template Hierarchy, Wordpress will choose default `archive.php` for custom taxonomy if no special template is specified.

That means you cannot not have `archive-product.php` to use with Custom Taxonomy archive.

In your case the - `example.com/product/?price=100` is archive for prodcts with custom taxonomy price set to 100.

Comment: Finally I solve it, but in a different way. I just create another custom taxonomy "Product", show now they can share the same taxonomy archive page to display the posts